# can't get Twilio helper library SMS example send to work

Tags: c#, twilio

[This Twilio example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp)

gets this error:

> - $exception  {"The 'From' number 9252223333 is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID."} Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException

Here is my C# source code:

```
using Twilio;  
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;
. . .


        // Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
        var accountSid = "my sid";
        // Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
        var authToken = "my token";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            to: new PhoneNumber("9252223333"),
            from: new PhoneNumber("9252223333"),
            body: "Hello from C#");

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

9252223333 is not my actual mobile#.

Comment: have you tried changing the number to different number? maybe adding +1 prefix will help?

Comment: Are you using a trial account? Is the number you are trying to send from verified in your account?

Comment: Is the From number a Twilio number that you have bought?

Answer (score 0):

Both your From number and To number are the same in your example.  And you mention that it is representative of your cellular phone number.  However, you can only send SMS via numbers you have bought from Twilio.  These purchased phone numbers must have the "SMS" feature enabled on them.

Answer (score 0):

1) From number should be twilio number . you can buy test number from your twilio test account
2) To number should be twilio verified if your working with twilio test account

Login to your account and hit this url.
https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified